# Installing Linux to USB drive on MacBook Pro - Can't find drive with UUID

Tags: fedora, boot, dual-boot, manjaro, macintosh

So I'm wanting to run a persistent Linux install off of a usb-c drive on my MacBookPro (13", 2017). Creating and booting to a live USB worked totally fine with Manjaro, Fedora, and ElementaryOS. ElementaryOS has some problems seeing the USB drive as valid install location (even though I'm totally able to format it using GParted). So I decided to try other distros since I'm not yet decided long term anyway.

With both Fedora and Manjaro I run into almost identical problems: I boot the live usb, I install to the destination USB drive, then when I boot to the destination it tells me it can't find a drive with a certain UUID.

Correction, with Fedora it worked at first, but after applying an update it then thew the error on the next boot.

On Manjaro it looks like this:

```
ERROR: device 'UUID=<LONG-UUID-HERE>' not found. Skipping fsck
mount: /new_root: can't find UUID=<SAME_UUID_HERE>.
You are now being dropped into an emergency shell.
sh: can't access tty: job control turned off
[rootfs ]#
```

While the Fedora one looks like this:

```
Warning: /dev/disk/by-uuid/<LONG-UUID-HERE> does not exist

Generating "/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt"

Entering emergency mode. Exit the shell to continue.
Type "journalctl" to view system logs.
You mgiht want to save "/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt" to a USB stick or /boot after mounting them and attach it to a bug report.

Press Enter for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue):
```

It's then totally unresponsive, can't get any keyboard inputs to show at all.

Anybody seen anything similar?

Comment: Record the UUID, boot on the live USB again, and then use `lsblk -o +uuid` or `blkid` to display the UUIDs of each visible filesystem. If the UUID can now be found, is it associated with a filesystem that is on the destination USB drive, or does it refer to a filesystem on the live USB? If the referred filesystem is on the *destination* USB, something is preventing the kernel from seeing it when booting on the new installation: most likely an important kernel module is not getting loaded.

Comment: Thanks, will check when I get home.